# Criar um usuário no linux e restringir ele a pasta e subpastas

Tags: linux

Olá, queria saber se é possível criar um usuário no linux e deixar ele em uma pasta, e não pode voltar a um nível acima somente poderá acessar as subpastas dentro dessa pasta.

/pasta/usuario/luiz < pasta em que a pessoa deve logar

/pasta/usuario < ele não pode vir para pasta anterior

/pasta/usuario/luiz/documentos < ele pode acessar subpastas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para alterar a pasta onde ele irá se logar, você deve editar dentro do arquivo /etc/passwd a seguinte informação:

marcosrai:x:1000:1000:Marcos Rai Alves da Cunha,,,:**/home/marcosrai**:/bin/zsh

Onde está em negrito deve colocar a pasta onde quer que o usuário esteja ao logar.

Para impedir que ele vá para os diretórios anteriores deve deixar as pastas anteriores com a permissão de usuário em 770 ou 700. Em 770, somente o dono do diretório e o grupo ao qual o diretório pertence terão acesso a ele, Já em 700 somente o dono do poderá acessá-lo.

Como você pode fazer isso? Ao dar um ls -l, você verá o seguinte resultado:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Dec 10 09:01  AndroidStudioProjects
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai      29537 Mar 22 09:12  arquivo_sispag.php
drwx------  8 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Mar  4 16:47  curso-react-native-master
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai    7320686 Apr 12 12:13  curso-react-native-master.zip
drwxrwxr-x  4 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Feb 17 15:13  cursos
drwxr-xr-x  4 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Apr  9 11:23  dev
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai  967991150 Apr 17 09:46  developer.zip
drwxrwxr-x 12 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Feb 17 15:24  dev_old
drwxr-xr-x  3 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Apr 11 17:39 'documentos locatario'
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai    3417907 Apr  8 10:33 'documentos locatario.zip'
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai      21680 Apr  8 09:16 'fio ramais e grupos.pdf'
drwxrwxr-x  2 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Mar 19 23:00  Mrai
drwxr-xr-x 10 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Apr 17 09:39  newsbit
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai      23428 Jan  8 20:00 'Planilha Despesas.ods'
drwxr-xr-x  7 marcosrai marcosrai       4096 Feb 12 10:05  scripts
-rw-rw-r--  1 marcosrai marcosrai      45045 Apr 11 08:50  test.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 marcosrai marcosrai 1769747341 Mar 22 09:52  traccar_315_21-03.sql
-rwxrwxrwx  1 marcosrai marcosrai 1577541648 Mar 12 15:22  traccar_315.sql
```

Onde encontrá marcosrai marcosrai, quer dizer que sou o dono e o grupo ao qual os diretórios pertencem.

Deixe os subdiretórios da home do usúario da forma em que ele seja o dono ou faça parte do grupo.

Para melhore informações acesse: http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/linux/permissoes-de-acesso-a-arquivos-e-pastas-pelo-terminal-no-linux/